# How to replace a Form Element by a custom one in ZF2?

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-form-element, service-locator, zend-form2

I'm struggling with the `MultipleCheckbox` and particularly with the problem, that the form validation fails, if no checkbox of the list is selected. (See details [here](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF2-571).)

To workaround the issue I want to replace the `Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox` by a custom one where I override the `getInputSpecification()` method:

**`Checkbox.php`**

```
namespace My\Form\Element;
use Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox as ZendCheckbox;
class Checkbox extends ZendCheckbox
{
    public function getInputSpecification()
    {
        $spec = parent::getInputSpecification();
        $spec['required'] = false;
        return $spec;
    }
}
```

**`module.config.php`**

```
return [
    'form_elements' => [
        'invokables' => [
            'Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox' => 'My\Form\Element\Checkbox',
        ],
    ]
];
```

But my custom `Checkbox` class has not replaced the on of Zend. It's not ignored completely -- I see with Xdebug, that it's used *in some cases* (e.g. for a `RadioButton` element and for some single `Checkbox` elements). But in some other cases (particularly for the checkboxes of my `MultiCheckbox`) not.

What am I doing wrong? How to replace a `Zend\Form\Element` for the whole application?

Comment: Zend's configuration are all combined in one file on bootstrap, and your configuration is thus erased by zend's inner configuration. You should name your invokables differently and create a CustomCheckbox (whatever your name is) element.

Comment: @automatix, looking at the code `Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox extends Zend\Form\Element\Checkbox` so you're probably going to have to also create a custom MultiCheckbox element which extends your custom Checkbox element and add that to form_elements config

Comment: @Crisp Yes, I've tried it out, it's not a good solution. After I created a custom `Checkbox` and `MultiCheckbox`, I saw, that I also needed to create a custom `FormMultiCheckbox` view helper. Zend classes seem to be hard-wired at this place, so it's not so easy to replace one with a custom implementation.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, not easy at all, there's a lot to replace depending on the element you're over-riding :-/